# How to "expand" a pandas dataframe from string/character?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I generated a pandas dataframe from a list of lists:

In:

```
lis = [['baby ferrets\ntype: mamal\n»age:2\n»food: Renal'],['dog\ntype: mamal\n»age: 3 months\n»food: dog food'], ['cat\ntype: mamal\n»age: 2\n»food: cat food'], ['bobcat (exotic pet)\ntype: mamal\n»age: 1\n»food: meat'], ['iguana\ntype: reptile\n»age: 2\n»food: crickets']]

df = pd.DataFrame(lis)
df
```

Out:

```
    0
0   baby ferrets\ntype: mamal\n»age:2\n»food: Renal
1   dog\ntype: mamal\n»age: 3 months\n»food: dog food
2   cat\ntype: mamal\n»age: 2\n»food: cat food
3   bobcat (exotic pet)\ntype: mamal\n»age: 1\n»food: meat
4   iguana\ntype: reptile\n»age: 2\n»food: crickets
```

How can I transform the previous dataframe into (*):

```
    pet, type, age, food
0   baby ferrets, mammal, 2, Renal
1   dog, mammal, 3 months, dog food
2   cat, mammal, 2, cat food
3   bobcat (exotic pet), mammal, 1, meat
4   iguana, reptile, 2, crickets
```

When I created a the pandas dataframe I tried to do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lis, sep= '\n')
```

I also tried to:

```
df['newcol'] = lis['pet'].str.extract('([A-Z]\w{0,})', expand=True)
df
```

However, I am not matching all the elements. Is it possible to get (*) format with pandas?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for parsing your column after it is loaded.

```
def parse_col(r):
    return pd.Series(data=[i.split(':')[-1] for i in r[0].split('\n')], index=['name', 'type', 'age', 'food'])

df.apply(parse_col, axis=1)

    name    type    age food
0   baby ferrets    mamal   2   Renal
1   dog mamal   3 months    dog food
2   cat mamal   2   cat food
3   bobcat (exotic pet) mamal   1   meat
4   iguana  reptile 2   crickets
```

Explanation:

The `parse_col` function above is receiving each row of the DataFrame as a pandas [`Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html), then using the string in the first and only element of this Series (`r[0]`). The string is then splitted by the `'\n'` character so each data field is a separate element of a list, and again by the `':'` character to separate lables from the actual data. Finally, the data is reassembled into another [`pd.Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) and returned. The `.apply()` DataFrame method simply applies the function above to each row of the frame.

This function can also be modified to parse the list prior to loading into a DataFrame.

Comment: @student, sure, added some explanation